# Possible combinations of teams at a tennis tournament

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Eight people decide to play a doubles tennis tournament. If they want to play matches in all possible pairings, how many matches will they play?

I tried to calculate this first in the following way:

No. of possible double matches: (8 nCr 4) = 70

No. of possible pairs with 4 people / match: 0.5 * (4 nCr 2) = 3

Hence, the number of matches will be 70 * 3 = 210.

Yet, I found a formula which states that the number of ways n*m objects can be divided into m groups, each containing n objects is given by:

(mn)! / ((n!)^m * m!), if the groups are indistinguishable.

In this case we would have 4 groups, each containing two elements (pairs).

(4*2)! / ((2!)^4) * 4!) = 105.

This is exactly half of the result above. Why is that? I mean since the tournament is played in pairs anyway, it should not matter whether we have a pair AB or BA; is is the same pair. If this reasoning is correct, then the right result would be the second one, i.e. 105. Am I right here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $105$ is the number of ways of diving $8$ people into $4$ groups of $2$ but that is not particularly helpful information as it does not tell you who plays who.

It might be better to use your second method with $m=2$ and $n=4$ to give $35$ ways of diving $8$ people into $2$ groups of $4$. Each group of $4$ needs to play $3$ matches, so $3+3=6$ matches between the two groups. So the second method would give $35 \times 6=630$ matches, confirming the result of the first method.

A third method that might be more easily generalised to other numbers of competitors would be to say there are ${8 \choose 2}=28$ possible pairs who each need to play ${8-2 \choose 2}=15$ other pairs but each match involves two pairs so in total there are $\frac{28 \times 15}{2}=630$ matches.